# jquery mouseover -- the box didn't move to follow the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want: when the cursor is moving above "tip1", the box showing "*this is my tip1*" will **follow** the cursor.

What actually shows: when the cursor is above "tip1", the box showing "*this is my tip1*" was **under** "tip1".

Code:

```js
$(function() {
  var x = 10;
  var y = 20;
  $("a.tooltip").mouseover(function(e) {
    this.myTitle = this.title;
    this.title = '';
    var tooltip = "<div id='tooltip'>" + this.myTitle + "</div>";
    $("body").append(tooltip);
    $("#tooltip")
      .css({
        "top": (e.pageY + y) + "px",
        "left": (e.pageX + x) + "px"
      }).show("fast");
  }).mouseout(function() {
    this.title = this.myTitle;
    $("#tooltip").remove();
  }).mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#tooltip")
      .css({
        "top": (e.pageY + y) + "px",
        "left": (e.pageX + x) + "px"
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="#" class="tooltip" title="this is my tooltip1">tip1.</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine. Are you sure you have included jquery correctly?

Comment: There must be some other mistake on your page that you haven't included in your code.  I created a fiddle copying and pasting your sample code and it worked as you require without any changes.

Comment: instead of chaining try putting mouse function seperately

Comment: Your code is working as expected. Try to run the snippet...

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/6t7k96bt/1/

```js
$(function () {
  var x = 10;
  var y = 20;
  $("a.tooltip").mouseover(function (e) {
      this.myTitle = this.title;
      this.title = '';
      var tooltip = "<div id='tooltip'>"+this.myTitle+"</div>";
      $("body").append(tooltip);
      $("#tooltip")
              .css({
                  "top": (e.pageY + y) + "px",
                  "left": (e.pageX + x) + "px"
              }).show("fast");
  }).mouseout(function () {
      this.title = this.myTitle;
      $("#tooltip").remove();
  }).mousemove(function (e) {
      $("#tooltip")
              .css({
                  "top": (e.pageY + y) + "px",
                  "left": (e.pageX + x) + "px"
              });
  });
});
```

```css
#tooltip{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="tooltip" title="this is my tip1">tip1.</a></p>
```

You forgot to add `css` to tooltip div. Add position as `absolute`.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

*«I want the box showing beside the "tip1"»*

OK... Then use a `span` instead of a `div`...
And use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `.append`.

It will add your message inside the `p`, right after "tip1".

```js
$(function () {
  var x = 10;
  var y = 20;
  $("a.tooltip").mouseover(function (e) {
    this.myTitle = this.title;
    this.title = '';
    //var tooltip = "<div id='tooltip'>"+this.myTitle+"</div>";
    var tooltip = "<span id='tooltip'>"+this.myTitle+"</span>";
    //$("body").append(tooltip);
    $(".tooltip").after(tooltip);
    $("#tooltip")
      .css({
      "top": (e.pageY + y) + "px",
      "left": (e.pageX + x) + "px"
    }).show("fast");
  }).mouseout(function () {
    this.title = this.myTitle;
    $("#tooltip").remove();
  }).mousemove(function (e) {
    $("#tooltip")
      .css({
      "top": (e.pageY + y) + "px",
      "left": (e.pageX + x) + "px"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#" class="tooltip" title="this is my tip1">tip1.</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="link">
    <a href="#" >tip1.</a>
    <div class="tootltip">
        <div class="tootltip-arrow"></div>
    This is tip1
    </div> 
</div> 

<style type="text/css">
.tootltip{
    background-color: rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.62);
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.tootltip-arrow
{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.62);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".link").mouseover(function(e)
    {
        var tootltip = $(this).find(".tootltip");
        tootltip.css("display","block");
    });

    $(".link").mouseout(function(e)
    {
        var tootltip = $(this).find(".tootltip");
        tootltip.css("display","none");
    });

</script>
</body>
```